# (Algebraic) derivations $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, partial-derivative, tangent-line, tangent-spaces

I have a basic question about a proof regarding the (algebraic) definition of **Derivations** forming a basis of the $n$-dimensional linear space of derivations.

> Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold, $a \in M$. Let $\bar f$ be the
>   germ of  a differentiable function $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ with $a \in U
> > \subset M$. Let $\mathcal{E}_{M,a}$ be the set of germs of
>   differentiable functions $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> A **Derivation** of $\mathcal{E}_{M,a}$ is a linear map $\delta:
>  \mathcal{E}_{M,a} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the product rule $$
>  \delta(\bar f \bar g) = \bar f(a)\delta(\bar g) + \bar g(a)\delta
>  (\bar f)$$
>
> for all $\bar f, \bar g \in \mathcal{E}_{M,a}$.

We denote the set of all derivations of $\mathcal{E}_{M,a}$ by $$\operatorname{Der}\mathcal{E}_{M,a}$$

We consider the derivations of $\mathcal{E}_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$.

> Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We define the
>    Derivations $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}:
>  \mathcal{E}_{\mathbb{R}^n,0} \to \mathbb{R}$$ via $\bar f \mapsto
>  (\partial/\partial x_j)f(0)$ (partial derivative with respect to the
>   variable $x_j$)

**Proposition:** The derivations $\partial/\partial x_j, j = 1,...,n$ form a basis of the linear space $\operatorname{Der}\mathcal{E}_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$

**Proof** We'll prove the linearly independence of $\partial/\partial x_j$. Let $$\sum_{i=1}^na_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = 0,\ a_j \in \mathbb{R}\ (*) $$

Thus

$$ a_k = \sum_{i=1}^n a_j\frac{\partial \bar{x}_k}{\partial x_j} = 0 \ (**)$$ for all $k$.

I don't understand the implication from $(*)$ to $(**)$

Can someone please elaborate? I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply the operator to $\bar{x}_k.$

Comment: hello cmk, how exactly? i get slightly confused whether $\bar x_k$ is of $\mathcal{E}_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$. i feel a bit lost.

Comment: By definition, $\partial/\partial x_j$ acts on $\bar{x}_k$ by returning $(\partial/\partial x_j)(x_k)(0)$. Just calculate what that is for each $j$. Does that help?

Comment: hello cmk, with peek-a-boos help, i actually got behind your first hint. it fully makes sense now, thanks a lot for the hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in $(*)$ that $\sum a_j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = 0$ means that if you apply this derivation on any germ of functions $[f]$, then you get the real number $0$. To prove linear independence, we need to prove each $a_k = 0$. So, in particular, lets choose $[f]$ to be the germ of one of the coordinate functions $[x_k]$. Recall that $x_k: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is the map $x_k(p^1, \dots, p^n) = p^k$.

Now, what does the partial derivative of this function $x_k$ with respect to the $j^{th}$ variable evaluated at $0$ $\partial_j(x_k)(0)$ equal? This is $1$ if $j=k$ and $0$ otherwise (because if $j \neq k$ then the function $x_k$ doesn't even depend on the $j^{th}$ variable). Thus,
\begin{align}
0 &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right)(x_k) \tag{by assumption}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \dfrac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_j}(0) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n a_k \delta_{kj} \\
&= a_k
\end{align}
where $\delta_{jk}$ is the kronecker delta symbol (1 if $j=k$, $0$ otherwise). This proves each $a_k = 0$ hence proves linear independence.

---

Looking at your comment, I hope you can first prove that with respect to the usual differentiable structure on $\Bbb{R}^n$, the coordinate functions $x_k : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ are indeed smooth. Hence, you can take their germ equivalence classes $[x_k]$. This will thus be an element of the space $\mathcal{E}_{\mathbb{R}^n,0}$. Hence, you can apply the derivation on this element.

So, strictly speaking, the derivation $\sum a_j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ should be evaluated on the germ $[x_k]$. But by definition, this is defined by its action on a representative in the equivalence class: $\bigg(\sum a_j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg)(x_k)$, and I hope you've proven somewhere that this definition is independent of which representative is chosen, and hence is well-defined. This justifies my argument above.

Comment: hello peek-a-boo. thank you very much for your very detailed anwser. i was sincerely hoping to get this kind of help. i will think things through and come back if i might have a question, but it looks very promising. thank you so much!

Comment: one question (that might have prevented my confusion). the coordinate function $x_k$ is basically just the canonical projection $\pi_k$, isnt it? whereas $\pi_k: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (x_1,...x_k,...,x_n) \mapsto x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Zest Yes that's exactly what it is. but what happens in this subject is that very often people use $x_k$ to mean both the $k$-th projection function, and also as the kth element in the tuple of numbers $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n$. This can be very confusing if it isnt pointed out (sure was for me). So in general, on an "abstract" manifold, if $(U,x)$ is a chart, $p \in U$ and $f$ is a function, whenever people write $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(p)$, what is really meant is the real number $\partial_j(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$.

Comment: thank you so much @peek-a-boo. i found it depressingly confusing, not knowing where all of a sudden $\bar{x_k}$ was from and what i was supposed to expect from it.

Comment: Here $f \circ x^{-1} : x[U] \to \Bbb{R}$ is a map from $x[U]$ which is an open subset of some $\Bbb{R}^n$, so it really makes sense to speak of its $j$th partial derivative $\partial_j(f \circ x^{-1})$ which is again a function $x[U] \to \Bbb{R}$, and ask what is its value on the element $x(p) \in x[U] \subset \Bbb{R}^n$. So, $\partial_j(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$ is the real number which is actually meant when we write $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(p)$

Comment: I fully understand you concern, I went through this a few months back, and at times, you even see expressions like $x_k(x_1, \dots x_n) = x_k$ where there are multiple meanings to the $x$'s on both sides of the equation. This shouln't be a problem as long as you distinguish what is the function and what is the point of evaluation. Likewise, the same warnings go for the functions $y_i$

Comment: Also, in the case of the simple manifold $\Bbb{R}^n$, we have the identity chart $(U = \Bbb{R}^n, x = \text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n})$. So, in this case $x_i := \pi_i \circ x = \pi_i \circ \text{id} = \pi_i$. Here, if $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is smooth and $p \in \Bbb{R}^n$, then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(p) := \partial_j(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p)) = \partial_j(f \circ \text{id}^{-1})(id(p)) = \partial_j(f)(p)$. So, the new "symbol" reduces to its usual meaning as we would expect in the case of the simple manifold.

Comment: I highly recommed you watch this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pepU_7NJSGM&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=6&t=0s by Dr Frederic Schuller on tangent spaces (in particular minute 53, but watch the entire thing :))

Comment: thanks for all the hints, i really appreciate your help. i will gladly watch the link you've provided. looking forward to seeing what's inside :)

Comment: another question: why is it important (or is it?) to choose $0$ as the relevant point, such that we look at $x(0)$ as the value of the germ of $x$? wouldn't any other point satisfy the same properties regarding the partial derivatives?

Comment: in your definition you're evaluating the derivatives at $0$, simply because you're considering the germs  $\mathcal{E}_{\Bbb{R}^n,0}$ at $0$. But if you read back to my general construction, I worked with an arbitrary point $p \in M$ in the manifold, and gave the corresponding generalization as $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p$ being the derivation at $p$ defined by sending the germ $[f]$ at $p$ to the number $\partial_j(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$. So the idea is that you evaluate the derivative at the same point you're considering the germs and derivations.